# What is the opposite of "workflow oriented" in UI

Tags: user-interface, namespaces, workflow, naming

We have software products and there exist two kinds of UI for two kinds of users. the first is a "workflow oriented" UI which heavyly make use of wizards and second we have classic UI which is more for advanced users because it is more complex and unguided and has lots of toolwindows and controls. 
For the first we chose "Workflows" as namespace, but for the latter the chosen name "Classic" was not liked by the deveopers because "Classic" implicated for some people that this UI would be some kind of old or obsolete. What could be a better name?

Comment: What name did you eventually choose? Did my answer help?

Comment: There is not yet a decision, but "unguided" is a good pick, we also think about naming the UI by the description of the user group which is using it, e.g. Research.

Answer (score 1):

Naming is hard!

If you are not bound to a workflow, I'd say you are embarking on an "unguided" or "unstructured" journey through the product.

Also in video games, if a game is open-ended it's described as "nonlinear", so that could work for you too.